# concourse start container failed: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF

Tags: concourse

- Env:amazon linux2
- kernel version: 4.14.198-152.320.amzn2.x86_64
- concourse version:v6.6.0
- Issue:

After I setup concourse on amazon EC2, I can login concourse web and create pipeline. But when I trigger the pipeline build, I got below error message:
**runc run: exit status 1: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:338: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF**

- Checking the backend log:

{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.622775204Z","level":"info","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.completing","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624243772Z","level":"debug","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.runc","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","message":"nsexec:601 nsexec started","session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624281598Z","level":"debug","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.runc","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","message":**"try_mapping_tool:240 nsenter: mapping tool not present: Operation not permitted"**,"session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624308669Z","level":"debug","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.runc","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e",**"message":"nsexec:889 nsenter: failed to sync with parent: read(SYNC_USERMAP_ACK): Invalid argument"**,"session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624328533Z","level":"debug","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.runc","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","message":"log pipe has been closed: EOF","session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624349468Z","level":"debug","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.runc","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","message":"container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:338: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF","session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624379918Z","level":"info","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.create.finished","data":{"bundle":"/home/concourse/worker/depot/2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","session":"99.3.2"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624412285Z","level":"error","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.runtime-create-failed","data":{"error":"runc run: exit status 1: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:338: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF","handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","session":"99.3"}}
{"timestamp":"2020-10-15T03:14:44.624429680Z","level":"info","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.create.containerizer-create.finished","data":{"handle":"2b4ce51a-c28d-4aac-7122-b82cd1cbb99e","session":"99.3"}}

- I already highlight the message which may cause this issue. Thank you
  to help me to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause is system missing some tools. I replace it using a new system image, then working fine.